# Windows npm install node-gyp error: libxslt command failed

Tags: python, node.js, windows, npm, node-gyp

For the last few days I've been trying to get node/npm installed on my Windows 10 VM and I've tried everything I found with no success.

I followed the [node-gyp setup instructions for Windows](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) which say to install Python3.7. The [npm microsoft-build-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools) are now deprecated and installed with the microsoft installer (which I used). i also installed the tool through visual studio, and tried `npm config set msvs_version 2015 -g` to try both 2015/2017. I have `node -v v16.13.1`, `node-gyp -v v8.4.1`, `npm 8.2`. Everytime I try `npm install` I just keep getting the same stacktrace

```
 C:\Users\dperrone1\Desktop\project\node_modules\libxslt
npm ERR! command failed

 LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\dperrone1\Desktop\project\node_modules\node1-libxmljsmt-myh\build\Release\xmljs-myh.lib' [C:\Users\dperrone1\Desktop\project\node_modules\libxslt\build\node-libxslt.vcxproj]

npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.1 found 

 gyp info find VS using VS2017 (15.9.28307.1745) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"

npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

"C:\\Users\\dperrone1\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\dperrone1\Desktop\project\node_modules\libxslt
```

none of the solutions around npm rebuild/deleting node_modules work, because after `npm install` fails it wipes away the node_modules it added. any suggestions please? anyway to use an alternative library?

Fixed: the problem turned out not to be the build tools themselves, but the modules the build tools were trying to build. I remove the dependencies `libxslt`, `xml`, `xml-parser`, `xml2js`, and `xmltojson`. The core issue was `libxslt` and for some reason npm was trying to find a non existent fork of this module. I had the same issues trying to install this on WSL, but removing those packages fixes it all around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: the problem turned out not to be the build tools themselves, but the modules the build tools were trying to build. I remove the dependencies libxslt, xml, xml-parser, xml2js, and xmltojson. The core issue was libxslt and for some reason npm was trying to find a non existent fork of this module. I had the same issues trying to install this on WSL, but removing those packages fixes it all around

Answer (score 0):

Problem is python and your VS tools.
On windows worked for me:

- Uninstall node.js
- Uninstall python
- Uninstall VS build tools
- Clear registry
  Then reboot your machine and try install with following ordering:
- 1. Install python set executable path
- 2. Install VS build tools (latest)
- 3. Install node.js (Latest LTS version) **Be carefully angular CLI and some other stuff does not work with latest non LTS node.js**

Then reboot your machine.
Try to run `npm install`

Also try to not use npm install from desktop.

*It's preferable to post your package json.*

Comment: Thanks! I just updated my post with the fix, it was just some troublesome modules that I couldn't get to build on Windows

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been bothering me, but I put node JS version down to 12.13.0 to solve the headache

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).